# Xcode in app email adding a From text field

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mfmailcomposer

Ok, so I have successfully made my first in-app Email app using MFMAilComposer. I have the toRecipients textfield added, as well as subject and body etc. So I understand that the email will not send if I use the simulator and will send with an iPhone. However, when a person receives the email, how is that person supposed to know whom he received it from? With this in mind, a "From" field should be in order. I appreciate all answers, and thanks in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set from in MFMailComposeViewController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982477/how-to-set-from-in-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to handle this, the mail composer does it for you. When the composer is shown it defaults to the users default email account but if they want to choose which email address they are sending from they can simply tap their email and a list will expand allowing them to choose from which of their emails to send the message.

Comment: Ah, so what you're saying is that my app with already knows the user's email via the email app, and that when my app is on an actual iPhone, it will display their email account?

Comment: @doc92606 That is correct, and if my answer has helped you be sure to upvote and mark as correct!

Comment: Well, once I get 15 rep that's the first thing I'll do xD

Comment: @doc92606 Thanks! But you should already be able to mark the answer as correct by clicking the "check mark"