# From field missing in MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Is it possible to include the `From` field in a `MFMailComposeViewController` so that if a user has more than one account on their device they can choose which email account to send an email from?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982477/how-to-set-from-in-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Comment: Yes - I looked at that question but it is not asking exactly the same thing. There is another question that where the answer is 'Tap the From field' but my question is how you get the From field displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no from field property. The user can select their email address inside the MFMailComposeViewController itself (while writing the email). Hard coding it in would be redundant. If a user has more than one email they can elect which one to choose from again, in the MFMailComposeViewController

Comment: That is what I want them to be able to do but when the email opens there is no From displayed. See updated question with image.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths test it on a real device. Changes are if your using simulator you haven't set up an email account for it

Comment: It is the same on my iPad

Comment: @RichardGriffiths tap on the cc/bcc field

Comment: @RichardGriffiths np. We've all been there

Comment: None of these answers are correct. Tapping on the CC field does not make the from field show in my app.

Comment: The answer is right, it’s just how it works. You can reproduce in any native application with a simple share action test. Nothing in the documentation has changed to imply otherwise. You must have done something else or it’s circumstantial. For example, Xcode/SDK may be bugged or iOS beta version is bugged etc. @johnrubythecat

Comment: Also, no default field shows up in the Mail settings in the Settings app. That's missing too.

Comment: Did you properly set up an email account on the device you’re trying to test on @johnrubythecat